# Distribute angular 2 project without ts file

Tags: javascript, angular

Could we distribute angular 2 project  only with js file without ts file? i have tried separate ts and js file with three steps

1. system.config.js : change app to dist

   ```
    var map = {
     'app':                        'dist', // 'dist',
     '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
   };
   ```
2. tsconfig.json : add  outDir: dist

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "removeComments": false,
     "noImplicitAny": false,
     "outDir": "dist"
   }
   ```
3. Create dist folder to root folder, than `npm start`, js file is created in dist folder.

everything ok.

but i would distribute the project only with js file, i have deleted all ts file, but when refresh my browser, get an error.

how to do that?

Comment: It really depends on what tools you are using to develop your app. What are you using? Angular-cli? Webpack?

Comment: no i only tried with 5 min quickstart, i do not use angular-cli, how to use it?

Comment: The quickstart shouldn't really be used for production. The typescript files don't go into production, mainly due to performance. You can check how to use angular-cli here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/install-angular2/2814/install-angular2-with-angular-cli#t=201607310138276455762

Comment: ok i will try, i suppose that angular 2 cli still in progres, so i did not use it. i will back if get any question.

Comment: @acdcjunior i have read about angularcli and webpack, but two of them still made me confuse, why angular team separate this two build system separately from package installer, why they don't take this in the angular 2  starter. so this is make me confuse, newbie like me will hesitate to use this framework, "you can make it but you can't use it in real world"